# Glide not Loading Image from the cloud storage

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am having an issue displaying images from my cloud storage,Glide keeps throwing this very long errors about exifinterface i have done some research concerning the issue but my problem doesnt seem to go away.
i have attached my stack trace below.

```
W/ExifInterface: Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.
    java.io.IOException: Invalid byte order: a3c
        at android.media.ExifInterface.readByteOrder(ExifInterface.java:3121)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.isOrfFormat(ExifInterface.java:2437)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.getMimeType(ExifInterface.java:2315)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1753)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:1447)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ExifInterfaceImageHeaderParser.getOrientation(ExifInterfaceImageHeaderParser.java:40)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParserUtils.getOrientation(ImageHeaderParserUtils.java:91)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler.decodeFromWrappedStreams(Downsampler.java:236)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler.decode(Downsampler.java:206)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.StreamBitmapDecoder.decode(StreamBitmapDecoder.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.StreamBitmapDecoder.decode(StreamBitmapDecoder.java:18)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapDrawableDecoder.decode(BitmapDrawableDecoder.java:58)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:72)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:55)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:45)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:58)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:43)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:515)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:480)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:466)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:418)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onDataFetcherReady(SourceGenerator.java:135)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onDataFetcherReady(SourceGenerator.java:135)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:74)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
2019-11-06 11:47:38.721 10368-10557/ke.co.upesy D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
2019-11-06 11:47:38.753 10368-10368/ke.co.upesy W/Glide: Load failed for https://storage.cloud.google.com/upesy-old/img/securex-mobile.jpg with size [-2147483648x-2147483648]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 4 causes:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{DirectByteBuffer->Object->Drawable}, DATA_DISK_CACHE, https://storage.cloud.google.com/upesy-old/img/securex-mobile.jpg
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (2 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{FileInputStream->Object->Drawable}, DATA_DISK_CACHE, https://storage.cloud.google.com/upesy-old/img/securex-mobile.jpg
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (3 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, DATA_DISK_CACHE, https://storage.cloud.google.com/upesy-old/img/securex-mobile.jpg
    There were 2 causes:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
        Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
      Cause (4 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{DirectByteBuffer->Object->Drawable}, REMOTE, https://storage.cloud.google.com/upesy-old/img/securex-mobile.jpg
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (5 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{FileInputStream->Object->Drawable}, REMOTE, https://storage.cloud.google.com/upesy-old/img/securex-mobile.jpg
2019-11-06 11:47:38.754 10368-10368/ke.co.upesy W/Glide:    Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (6 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, REMOTE, https://storage.cloud.google.com/upesy-old/img/securex-mobile.jpg
    There were 2 causes:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
        Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
2019-11-06 11:47:38.755 10368-10368/ke.co.upesy I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 4)
    java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder.decode(VideoDecoder.java:173)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:72)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:55)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:45)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:58)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:43)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:515)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:480)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:466)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:418)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:74)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:276)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:142)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder$ParcelFileDescriptorInitializer.initialize(VideoDecoder.java:296)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder$ParcelFileDescriptorInitializer.initialize(VideoDecoder.java:291)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder.decode(VideoDecoder.java:161)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:72) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:55) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:45) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:58) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:43) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:515) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:480) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:466) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:418) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:74) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:276) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446) 
2019-11-06 11:47:38.757 10368-10368/ke.co.upesy I/Glide: Root cause (2 of 4)
    java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder.decode(VideoDecoder.java:173)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapDrawableDecoder.decode(BitmapDrawableDecoder.java:58)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:72)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:55)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:45)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:58)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:43)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:515)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:480)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:466)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:418)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:74)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:276)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:142)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder$ParcelFileDescriptorInitializer.initialize(VideoDecoder.java:296)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder$ParcelFileDescriptorInitializer.initialize(VideoDecoder.java:291)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder.decode(VideoDecoder.java:161)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapDrawableDecoder.decode(BitmapDrawableDecoder.java:58) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:72) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:55) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:45) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:58) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:43) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:515) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:480) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:466) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:418) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:74) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:276) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446) 
2019-11-06 11:47:38.759 10368-10368/ke.co.upesy I/Glide: Root cause (3 of 4)
    java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder.decode(VideoDecoder.java:173)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:72)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:55)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:45)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:58)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:43)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:515)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:480)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:466)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:418)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onDataFetcherReady(SourceGenerator.java:135)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onDataFetcherReady(SourceGenerator.java:135)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.FileLoader$FileFetcher.loadData(FileLoader.java:76)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:387)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onDataFetcherReady(SourceGenerator.java:135)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:95)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ByteBufferFileLoader$ByteBufferFetcher.loadData(ByteBufferFileLoader.java:74)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.startNext(DataCacheGenerator.java:75)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at
```

This is the code to display the image

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(path).into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                    holder.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(resource);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/commit/02f47e0b7506b9595cb8c7019edbf722726792d7 am trying to understand the implementation of this fix but ma not able to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this dependency for glide

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.60"
```

Comment: I am currently using `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'`

Comment: please try with above dependency. 4.0.0

Comment: After bumping up my glide version to 4.11.0 ti have not experienced this issue again

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide version `4.11.0` or later

### build.gradle

```
def glide_version = "4.11.0"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
```

GL

[Source](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases)